# Database to Excel charts (or pdf)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, charts

Hi guys I have a simple DB that has two fields in it (time and number 1-3), the data needs to be exported and shown in simple charts (horizontal bars from 0 to max time from my DB)? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Which database it is? SQL, Oracle ?

Comment: it's a T-SQL database

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4902/generate-charts-rapidly-with-sql-server-using-r-and-tsql/  This may help

Comment: T-SQL is not a database, it'a a language. It's used by Sybase and Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes I meant SQL Server

Comment: Excel actually has a database connection module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-excel. This is refreshable and you can write actual tsql queries to pull data.

Comment: If you need it to be 100% "automated", you'll want to look into SQL Server Reporting Services or a similar reporting platform. You aren't going to get a 100% copy-and-paste solution on Stack Overflow because A) that's not how the site works and B) it's a much larger topic than can be answered in this format.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest was to establish a direct data access from excel to SQL-Server and use Excel's abilities for the graphics.

If you need the data "exported", it is quite easy to get a table as CSV-list. Again this can be opened with Excel directly to do the graphical work there.

Depending on your environment you might think about any reporting tool, obviously the first choice was SSRS or PowerBI, which is *part of the box*.

You might even use a `SELECT * FROM YourTable` and just *copy-and-paste* the full result into Excel.

The main things to think about:

- One-time action or regularly
- Grade of automatism
- Size of data / Count of rows
- Location / Access-rights / Linkability of your systems
- Existing tools

Comment: It needs to be fully automated.
It looks like so:
I have a HMI panel. on this panel I choose a custom range of time. Then after I click the raport button it needs to make a select query for me with this custom time range (that's done). Then it would need to make a report with graphs that would look like this: https://imgur.com/U8rAHg8

Comment: @AdamDominiak You cannot expect any *copy-and-paste-ready-made-magic-oh-I'm-so-happy* solution for this... This depends on so many factors we do not know... If you can establish direct data access from Excel to SQL-Server you will find everything you need. You might even create VBA-enhanced user-forms...

Comment: Sup @AdamDominiak ; look at this url if you need to pass params to sql db.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3436/passing-dynamic-query-values-from-excel-to-sql-server/
; but like Shnugo is saying you need a game plan for questions suggested by him. From what i rem correctly by default you cannot pass params to external data source from excel (we have a lot of views at my previous work). So yes your using excel RAM to filter data (hint: will be slow) . We are here to guide you not do your work for you. :)